# Angularjs error when executing factory

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am new Angularjs developer. I want to make login page with authentication from PHP, when i submit the form, it run $scope.login code.

I've angular code like this

```
var module = angular.module('figi-login', ['onsen']);

          module.controller('AppController', function($scope) { });
          module.controller('PageController', 
          ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'AuthenticationService',
          function($scope,$http,$location, AuthenticationService) {
            ons.ready(function() {
                // AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
                $scope.formData = {};

                $scope.login = function(){
                    AuthenticationService.Login($scope.formData)
                        .success(function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        });
                };
            });

          }]).factory('AuthenticationService',
          ['$http','$rootScope',
            function($http,$rootScope){
                var service = {};

                service.Login = function(formData){
                    return $http({
                        method  : 'POST',
                        url     : 'http://10.0.2.2/demo/api/login.php',
                        data    : $.param(formData),
                        headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                    });

                };
          }]);
```

when login is executed, it should be calling service.Login in factory. i get error like this

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Login' of undefined

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return the `service` in your *AuthenticationService factory*:

```
return service;
```

See the commented line at the end of the factory:

```
.factory('AuthenticationService',
      ['$http','$rootScope',
        function($http,$rootScope){
            var service = {};

            service.Login = function(formData){
                return $http({
                    method  : 'POST',
                    url     : 'http://10.0.2.2/demo/api/login.php',
                    data    : $.param(formData),
                    headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                });
            };
            return service;  //this line is missing
      }])
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to re-write your factory like so:

```
.factory('AuthenticationService',
      ['$http','$rootScope',
        function($http,$rootScope){
            return{   //The return will make your function available in the controller
              Login: function(formData){
                  return $http({
                      method  : 'POST',
                      url     : 'http://10.0.2.2/demo/api/login.php',
                      data    : $.param(formData),
                      headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                  });
               };
           }
}]);
```

Altenatively, you can write it service style:

```
.service('AuthenticationService',
      ['$http','$rootScope',
        function($http,$rootScope){
            this.Login = function(formData){
                return $http({
                    method  : 'POST',
                    url     : 'http://10.0.2.2/demo/api/login.php',
                    data    : $.param(formData),
                    headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                });
            };
}]);
```

Both of these writeups are somewhat more conventional. You can call either of them with:

```
AuthenticationService.Login($scope.formData)
```